# A Scheme function to compose other functions

Tags: scheme, variadic-functions, anonymous-function, function-composition, chez-scheme

I wish to create a function that can compose two functions into one. Given `g` and `f`, it should create a function `h` provides the output of `f` as input to `g`. Here was my result:

```lisp
(define (compose g f)
    (lambda (.args)
        (g (apply f (if (atom? .args) (list .args) .args)))))
```

The following snippet works with `compose`.

```lisp
(display ((compose add1 add1) 3))
```

However, I cannot figure out why the example below won't work. I provided the error message that I got below, and I am using Chez Scheme 9.5.2. The error here probably has to do with the variadic nature of `compose`, but that's just an idea. Does anyone know why my second test isn't working as expected?

```lisp
(define (reduce f lst seed)
    (if (null? lst) seed
        (f (car lst) (reduce f (cdr lst) seed))))

(define product-of-incremented-list
    (compose
        (lambda (lst) (reduce * lst 1))
        (lambda (lst) (map add1 lst))))

(display (product-of-incremented-list '(3 4 5)))
; I was expecting 120, because (3 4 5) -> (4 5 6) and (4 5 6) -> 120
; I'm getting an error instead:
; Exception: incorrect number of arguments to #<procedure at compose.scm:285>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `.args` to mean "a list of arguments", perhaps by analogy with `(lambda (x . more) ...)`, but this is not correct. `.args` is just a symbol like any other, so you have written a function that takes one argument named `.args`. Then when you discover your argument is a list, you `(apply f '(3 4 5))`. But the lambda you are using for `f` does not expect three arguments, it expects a single list argument. Thus the error.

Instead, the way to say "a list of arguments" is

```
(lambda args
  ...)
```

In general, what you write after the lambda is how to treat the input argument list. If you put a list like `(x y)` there, then the argument list is expected to be two components, `x` and `y`. For `(x . more)`, the first element is named `x`, and then the rest of the list is named `more`. If you just want the list as-is, you simply give it a name: here, `args`.

Your second issue is this checking of whether the arguments are a list or an atom. This is silly: you can be certain it will always be a list, because you do not break down the input parameters. So,

```
(define (compose f g)
  (lambda args
    (f (apply g args))))
```